# How to give the path of file that is to be trained for object detection

Tags: python, opencv, object, detection

instead of command line arguments I want to load the our class labels and then train the image that is uploaded by web page created using flask

I have tried different ways of giving the path of file (class label).

this code is regarding command line.

```
labelsPath = os.path.sep.join([args["yolo"], "coco.names"])
```

`yolo` is the argument given along with image argument.

what I have to give in place of `args["yolo"]`. to load the model `cooco.names` when python file is executed.

Comment: Hi, can you edit your question to show the front and back end code?

Answer (score 0):

PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(**file**)

or you can perform a search for that file from the root folder like

```
dir_path = os.path.dirname('/')
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir_path):
     for file in files:
        if file ==' your file name':
                 file_path = root + '/'+str(file)
                 break
```

PS : This works for Linux versions only, windows may need different config like \ instead of /

Comment: I need for windows